# Archive to Gmail Fails, but only when using the Archive Button on the Toolbar

Tags: macos, mail.app, gmail

If I try to archive an email using the toolbar 'archive' button I get this error message:

"The IMAP command “UID COPY” (to Archive) failed for the mailbox “INBOX” with server error: No folder Archive (Failure)."

However, if I manually drag the email to all mail, it archives just fine.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Mail.app / Preferences / Accounts / MailBoxes** and under *Trash*, uncheck *Store deleted messages on the server*.

Usually this does the trick.